# Is $A = f\mathbb{R^2}$ complete? $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^3}$, $f(x,y) = (x,y,x^2-y)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My question is pretty much what it says in the headline.
Is $A = f\mathbb{R^2}$ complete, where $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^3}$, $f(x,y) = (x,y,x^2-y)$, $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}$.

$f\mathbb{R^2}=$$\{ f(x,y), (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \}$

My initial thought is that as $f\mathbb{R^2}$ is $f$:s image (i.e. "set of values"), $f\mathbb{R^2}=\mathbb{R^3}$, but I'm not sure, and I'm not sure how could I show this. It is not intuitively clear to me because $x^2-y$, i.e. the third component of $f$ depends on the other two components.

Anyway if it was so that $f\mathbb{R^2} = \mathbb{R^3}$, we know that $\mathbb{R^3}$ is complete, so the image in question would be complete as well.

Any comments on how I tried to approach this. Any suggestions on other approaches? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces.  If $V \subset X$, define the *graph* of a function $f: V \to Y$ to be the set $\big\{(x, f(x) \; : \; x \in V \big\} \subset X \times Y$.  $X \times Y$ is itself a metric space under the metric $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2, y_2)) = d(x_1, y_1) + d(x_2, y_2)$, or $\sqrt{d(x_1, y_1)^2 + d(x_2, y_2)^2}$ if you prefer.  (Any of the $p$-norms are topologically equivalent, i.e. the same sets are closed and open in the product metric space.)

**Proposition.** Let $V \subset X$ be closed, and let $f : V \to Y$ be continuous.  Then the graph of $f$ is closed in $X \times Y$.

*Proof.*
Let $(x,y)$ be a limit point of the graph of $f$.
Then there exist $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ such that $(x_n, f(x_n)) \to (x,y)$.
In particular, this means $x_n \to x$ and $f(x_n) \to y$.

- Since $V$ is closed, $x_n \to x$ implies $x \in V$.
- Since $f$ is continuous, $x_n \to x$ implies $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.  Since $f(x_n) \to y$ also, we must have $f(x) = y$.

Therefore $(x,y)$ is the graph of $f$, and so the graph of $f$ is closed. $\square$

---

In your case, we have that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is closed, so the graph of the function $g(x,y) = x^2 - y$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Since $\mathbb{R}^3$ is complete, this closed subset must additionally be complete.

Comment: And I don't fully undestand this implication:
$\mathbb{R^2}$ is closed, so the graph of the function is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: @souf $\mathbb{R}^2$ is closed, and $g$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $g$ is defined on a closed set.  That allows us to use the theorem, which says that the graph of $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is closed. And remember that the graph of $g$ is given by $(x,y, x^2 - y)$, and is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @souf $y$ is not in the $A$ in your question.  $y$ is a real number.

Comment: On the first comment: oops, sorry. 
On the second. I still don't follow you, sorry. 

Say, for example, $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=e^x$. Now the domain is closed (in $\mathbb{R}$), but $f\mathbb{R}=]0,∞[$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @souf The thing you are confused about in the proposition is that we are talking about the *graph* of $f$, not the image of $f$.  The *graph* of $e^x$ is not $]0, \infty[$, but rather the set of points $(x, e^x)$, *a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$*.

Comment: Sorry, this is extra difficult because this is the first time I try to use these terms in english.
Anyway $f\mathbb{R^2}= \{ f(x,y),(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \}$

Comment: @souf: Note that $f\mathbb{R}^{2}=\mathrm{graph}(g)$, where $g:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ as Goos defined above. So you only need to show that the graph of $g$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ because closed subsets of complete spaces are complete.

Comment: @souf I am sorry for your difficulty communicating here in english.  I would be happy to discuss this in chat if you are still confused.  As in Thomas' comment, the "graph" and the "image" are two distinct concepts.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the definitions and thought about this, and I think I got it. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, I'm pretty sure I got it now. And I think I understood the idea of homeomorphisms better. 
Yes, thank you for pointing out the two different concepts. I still think it is *image* I was trying to refer to. I think my course book uses unorthodox notations every now and then.
According to my course book

Let $f:X \to Y$ and $A$ subset of $X$. 
Now $fA = \{ f(x),x \in A \}$. This is what the course book calls the image of f.

So now to answer the question whether $fA$ is complete, I can define the functions
$f_1: X \to fX$, $f(x,y) = (x,y,x^2-y)$ and $g: fX \to X$, $g:(x,y,z)=(x,y)$. [Note that here $z \in fX$, so that it obeys $z=x^2-y$]

So $f_1$ and $g$ are continuous. 
Moreover $g (f(x,y)) = (x,y)$ and $f(g(x,y,z))=(x,y,x^2-y)$, the identity functions. (At least, so they are called in my book). 
So now we see that $f_1$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $fX$, where $X=\mathbb{R^2}$.

And, as $\mathbb{R^2}$ is complete, so must $f\mathbb{R^2}$ be also complete.

Comment: This is a neat solution!

Comment: "I still think it is image I was trying to refer to."  Yes, you are right, it is the image.  But you can *show* that image is *equal* to the *graph* of a *different* function, and hence it suffices to show the graph of that other function is closed.  Which is what my answer was trying to explain.  Ah well.

Comment: Thanks!
And oh, I see now.